# Paypal Encrypted Button with Open SSL

Tags: php, paypal, openssl

I am new to the whole button encryption with paypal.  It seemed like all I had to do is what is explained on this page  http://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/articles/paypal_button_encryption_php.php 
but it seems more like than just a plug in play.  Seems as though I need Open SSL.  I use hosting and don't know if I have the right to install Open SSL on my server or should I just get SSL in the first place since I will be using it in the next couple of months. Currently I have a apache server with cpanel. Any advice would be great.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can also use an openssl installation on your desktop. OpenSSL does not equal 'an SSL certificate'. You simply need to create a keypair to sign the button code with.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a bear to install and get working with your PHP code. The workaround is to not encrypt, but use a hash to detect tampering, and then reconfirm the hash when the IPN is processed. I explain this here:

[How do I make a PayPal encrypted buy now button with custom fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14489512/105539)